# Does $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2^k}{k^2}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2^k}{k^2}$ converges?

Well, I know theoretically, that $\cos 2^k$ is ranged from $-1$ to $1$, which means atleast to me, that the denominater $k^2$ will be bigger for $k > 1$, which means it will probably converge to zero. but if $a_n$ converges to zero, it is not necessarily means that the sum of $a_n$ converges to zero.

P.S. $\frac{\cos 2^k}{k^2} = a_n$

Apart from that, I don't know how to solve that. that is just what I can say about that. hope you can help somehow. (In the exam, even if I know the solution theoretically, I need to prove it).

Comment: It's easy to see it converges absolutely, just compare to $\sum\frac1{k^2}$.  But I don't think it's easy to figure out what it converges to (definitely not zero).  Are you sure that's $\cos 2^k$ and not $(\cos 2)^k$?  That would make it a whole lot easier.

Comment: @GregoryGrant It is $cos2^k$

Comment: I seriously doubt this number has a nice closed form, or actually any closed form which we could find using modern tools.

Comment: @Wojowo I just need to say if it convergers or not.

Comment: @Wojowu I know, I've edited that now. sorry!

Comment: In this case, just follow Gregory's suggestion to prove the sequence is convergent absolutely.

Comment: $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\cos 2^k}{k^2}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So I can say that the sum is converges to 2? and why did you wrote $\frac{\pi^2} {6}$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: no, $a\leq 2$ does not imply $a=2$. I wrote $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ because $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So I can say that because $a_n <= 2$, It converges to a limit (which is not infinity) and thus $a_n$ converges.

Comment: If $a_n=(-1)^n$ then this is also true but $\sum a_n$ does not converge?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: here we are just using the fact that if $\sum_{n\geq 1} |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n$ converges, too.

Comment: Numerically, $-0.75$ seems to be an upper bound (This holds from $100$ to $12000$ terms for all cases I checked... $10000$ to $12000$ terms gives $-0.755783$, but I was using Mathematica Online and I began to go over my available memory pas $12000$, and I am not sure how quickly this series converges. Nevertheless, I would guess $-0.75$ would remain an upper bound, as the next digit seems to be converging from above and below to a non-zero digit as I add more terms)